# Need help removing "the jurys" page from Uni template

Tags: templates, page

so, I'm finishing my internship and my uni supervisor is forcing me into using my uni latex template, the problem is that the template is oriented for thesis and dissertations and I'm only doing an internship report, as such I don't need the "the jury" page.

I'm a noob in latex, I have been studying it for the past week, anyway, I have been messing with the files and can't find where the jury input page is.

Would really appreciate some help.

[one version of the template is publicly available on github:](https://github.com/fabiomaia/ua-thesis-template)

Also if someone could check one thing, when I compile, I get a cover.pdf and a matter.pdf, I'm guessing the only one that matters is the matter.pdf?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It seems to be lines 539--545 in the `uaThesisTemplate.sty` file. Try  commenting these lines to see if it is enough.

Comment: hey! thanks a lot! that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

> Welcome to TeX SX! It seems to be lines 539--545 in the uaThesisTemplate.sty file. Try commenting these lines to see if it is enough. – Bernard

this fixed the problem.

thanks for the quick help.